# Spring Security Basic Authentication Filter Issue with Spring Boot

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, jersey

We are working on Spring Boot application with Jersey and Basic Authentication Spring Security.Below are some files which i had used for configuration.

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


    @Value("${spring.datasource.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String dataSourceUrl;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {


            DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
            driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(dataSourceUrl);
            driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(username);
            driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(password);

            auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(driverManagerDataSource).usersByUsernameQuery(
                    "select username,password, user_status from users where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                    "select user.username,ur.role from users user inner join user_roles ur on user.role=ur.role_id and user.username=?");   

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()


                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").hasRole("SUPERADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/api/v1/**").hasRole("SUPERADMIN")


                .antMatchers("/api/v1/admin/**").hasAnyRole("SUPERADMIN","ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/api/v1/admin/**").hasAnyRole("SUPERADMIN","ADMIN")

                .antMatchers("/api/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER","SUPERADMIN","ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/api/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER","SUPERADMIN","ADMIN")

                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/login").permitAll()

                .and().httpBasic(); 


                }
}
```

**Also We have put CORS Filter for OPTIONS method so please check below FIlter.**

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        if(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("options") && response != null){
            System.out.println("in options");
            response.setStatus(200);
        }

        if(request.getHeader("Origin")!= null){
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin")); 
        }
        else {
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost");
        }

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");


        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}

}
```

It was given 401 unauthorization Error we are trying Jquery/Ajax Call so please check this and let me know how to solve filter issue with Spring Security.

Comment: For starters your url patterns are wrong. The order in which they are added is also the order in which they are consulted. So anything that starts with `/api/v1` is only accessible by someone with the `SUPERADMIN` role.

Comment: Yes, but i want to make chain base access of my all user like chain SUPERADMIN can access `/api/v1/` but actual problem is Header not authenticated. If i gives  `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/api/v1/**").pemitAll()` then it's working

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Basically what I'm explaining is that your `/api/v1/admin/**` mapping is useless as well as the /api/v1/login` as they will all be match by the preceding `/api/v1/**`

Comment: ok, but it is working all roles based authentication , It is not working when i am trying to access from Jquery/ajax it will gives error. so issue is OPTIONS methods not an url mapping.

Comment: Why would te ajax request be an issue, make sure you are sending all the appropriate information (cookies, headers etc.).

Comment: i am sending only headers not any other data when page will call OPTIONS method each time it gives `401 unauthorization`.

Comment: But are you sending the correct headers... If there is no session cookie or authentication cookie then there is no way in knowing which request it is hence a 401.

Comment: but it's working on REST client IDE like POSTMAN or RESTEasy.

Comment: So. That isn't your ajax call, if your call is missing the header for authentication it is never going to work. Those clients include the correct headers, so if postman works the issue is your ajax call not including the correct headers.

Comment: when you are using jquery then first it will call with OPTIONS method for get session or cookies then it will call correct url but unfortunately OPTIONS methods give error.

Comment: Not with us, so not sure what you are doing. Post that code...